# Input type matching for following characters in html5

Tags: html

How to design a patter to accept following characters and numbers with alpin html5  /!@#%?&*()-+= . Thanks in advance.. `jsfiddle.net/5dtk5/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to specify the regular expression.

Try something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$`

Comment: You have to add it to the regexp, but make sure to escape: `^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\/\(+=._-]+$`

Comment: what are all the characters should be escaped..Please give any reference

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions